# How to give Solaar root permission on startup

Tags: permissions, lubuntu, mouse, logitech-unifying

I have a Logitech M315 mouse with a nano receiver and have Solaar installed so that I can use it on mu Lubuntu laptop. Solaar runs on startup like I would expect it to, but whenever I plug in my nano receiver Solaar says:

```
Found a Logitech Receiver (/dev/hidraw1), but did not have permission to open it.

If you've just installed Solaar, try removing the receiver and plugging it back in.
```

The only way for this message to disappear and get Solaar to work correctly is to open a terminal and run`sudo solaar`. I take this to mean that it requires root permission to open the USB device read/write. I use Solaar to pair/unpair my devices so having a terminal hanging around all the time is both annoying and RAM-consuming (my laptop only has 512MB physical RAM).

The only way I know how to fix this is from back in my UNIX days where you put it in `/etc/profile`, but this only runs in Linux is the user logs in at a text mode shell (via a terminal or Ctrl-Alt-F2). Is there another way to give Solaar root permission at startup so that my mouse will work and I can get this annoying message out of my face?

Comment: See also my full installation and setup instructions here: [How do I install and configure the latest version of `solaar` to manage my Logitech wireless mouse or keyboard on Linux Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1390784/327339).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a udev rule to give the current seated* user read/write privileges to the HID device representing the Logitech Unifying USB receiver. An example of such a rule can be found in the [Solaar rules.d/42-logitech-unify-permissions.rule](https://github.com/pwr/Solaar/blob/master/rules.d/42-logitech-unify-permissions.rules) file.

You mentioned (un)pairing and a M315 mouse. If that is all you need, you can also try the `solaar-cli` tool which immediately exits after pairing. Alternatively, you can use the small `ltunify` utility which is describes [at this page](https://lekensteyn.nl/logitech-unifying.html#ltunify) (basic invocation: `ltunify pair` and `ltunify unpair`).

As an additional note on file permissions, do note that anyone who can read from the hidraw device is able to intercept your mouse motions (and keyboard strokes if you have a wireless keyboard). If you are worried about that, do not install the udev rule and instead stick to `sudo`.

*) seated means the user who is physically at the computer. This excludes SSH users for example who are not physically logged in.

Comment: I copied the contents from GitHub to the file in rules.d and it still doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @nkeck72 What Ubuntu version are you using? For really old versions (Ubuntu 12.10 and older) you have to uncomment line 36. If you are not yet in the "plugdev" group, either change it to your username or add yourself to it.

Comment: I'm using lubuntu 15.10

Comment: And what does "not working" mean? You still get the error even after placing it in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and re-inserting the USB receiver?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: I have added myself to the `plugdev` group, but I am still getting the error message. I added myself through the GUI (on Lubuntu: System Tools > Users and Groups). I have rebooted my laptop and am still getting the error. Suggestions?

Comment: Can you invoke the `lsusb -d 046d:` command? The product id (c52b for Logitech Unifying receivers) should appear in the rules file. Can you also check the permissions for the USB device? `ls -l /dev/hidraw1` should show show a different group (if you uncommented that) or `crw-rw-----+` for the permissions (when you have the `uaccess` tag enabled, the `+` signifies the application of an ACL). With `getfacl /dev/hidraw1` you should then see a line such as `user:yourusername:rw-`.

Comment: I had the file in the wrong directory, I placed it in udev instead of in udev/rules.d